# I've installed the Google voice and video chat web browser plugin, but Gmail doesn't detect it

Tags: gmail, google, google-voice, google-talk

I want to use Google voice and video chat on Iceweasel 10.0.4 on Debian Linux 6.0.5.  (Iceweasel is the Firefox derivative that comes with Debian Linux.)  I've installed Google's voice-and-video Web-browser plugin package.  It actually includes two browser plugins:  "Google Talk Plugin" and "Google Talk Plugin Video Accelerator".

I don't need video chat.  So I've used Firefox's add-ons manager to disable the Video Accelerator plugin [edit: I didn't know it's a mistake to disable it].

But:

- When I try to voice-chat with a contact, I get the error message:  "[Click here](http://tools.google.com/tools/dlpage/res/talkvideo/openinstallpage.html?hl=en#mail) to add voice/video chat."
- When I try to call a telephone from within Gmail, I get the error message:  "Please download the voice plugin to make a call."
- When I go to Settings > Chat, as the "I'm unable to make or receive phone calls in Gmail" [troubleshooter](http://support.google.com/chat/?topic=30052) recommends, I don't see any version information.  I just see:  "Gmail voice and video uses Flash for video rendering.  [Install Now](http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer)".

Why am I getting these error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these error messages were shown because I've disabled the video-accelerator plugin. To fix the problem, re-enable that plugin, then close and reopen Gmail.